# Use of BOOST thread attributes causes bind compile error

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, compilation, bind

Ok.. First of all, I have to say I'm using BOOST with its source (I have to). 
I'm both a BOOST and a C++ newbie, but I'm not new to coding (I'm rather used to managed languages). I met this problem in a somewhat large project, then I reproduced it in this little code snippet I'm presenting here:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void foo(int bar) {
    printf("Chu %d!",bar);
}

int main() {
    boost::thread_attributes attrs;

    boost::thread causeTrouble(attrs,foo,42); // <-- Probably problematic line
    causeTrouble.join();
}
```

According to [BOOST 1.52.0 Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial) this snippet should both compile and run fine; however, it gives me a weird compilation problem in a BOOST library header file (no other errors or warnings are present):

```
<boost_path>/bind/bind.hpp:313: error: no match for call to '(boost::thread_attributes) (void (*&)(int), int&)
```

To me, it looks like there's no actual boost::thread(boost::thread_attributes,F f) constructor, even if it should be according to the previously linked documentation.
Anyway, what's funny is that both the following lines *do compile fine*:

```
boost::thread noTrouble(attrs,foo);
```

and

```
boost::thread noTroubleEither(foo,42);
```

Even if I thoroughly searched StackOverflow and the rest of the Internet, I don't know where to turn my head :( In fact this is the first time I'm forced to actually *ask a new question*. Help!

Comment: I'm using a GCC compiler

Comment: Which version? Does it support variadic templates and rvale references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say,

> it looks like there's no actual boost::thread(boost::thread_attributes,F f)

That's not the constructor you're trying to call though. You're calling `boost::thread(attrs, foo, 42)`.  Based off the link, it looks like there's no `boost::thread(boost::attributes, F, Args)` constructor implemented, hence the complaint.

Try first using `boost::bind` explicitly to bind the `42` into `foo` and the starting the thread on the bound function object.

Something like this:

```
boost::function< void > f = boost::bind( foo, 42 );
boost::thread( attrs, f )
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please provide a code sample? (Thanks anyway)

Comment: Ok this worked:

    boost::thread causeTrouble(attrs,boost::bind(foo,42));

However, it's now giving a different problem in the large project (I have 8 integer arguments there) but it's a start anyway. Tomorrow I'll try to fix it and if I have problems I'll post again. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok looks like the other problem was due to an unrelated mistake I made on the bigger project. It now compiles fine! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a forwarding problem. Try defining an `int` variable with the value 42 and passing that as the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

The needed overload

```
template <class F, class Arg, class ...Args>
thread(attributes const& attrs, F&& f, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
```

is defined only if the compiler supports variadic templates and rvalue references. This could explain your problem.

I guess the documentation could be improved to signal this clearly. Please could you create a Trac ticket to follow this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `boost::bind`, like this:

```
boost::function< void > f = boost::bind( foo, 42 );

boost::thread( attrs, f )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide stacksize to the attributes, here is an example:

```
    #include <boost/thread.hpp>
    #include <boost/chrono.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    void wait(int seconds)
    {
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{seconds});
    }

    void thread()
    {

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
        wait(1);
        std::cout << i << '\n';
        }
    }
    catch (boost::thread_interrupted&) {}
    }

    int main()
    {
    boost::thread::attributes attrs;
    attrs.set_stack_size(1024);
    boost::thread t{attrs, thread};
    t.join();
    }
```